# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TodosController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The full text of the error message is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TodosController#index 
Couldn't find User with id=2
Rails.root: /home/randy/rubystack-1.9.3-29/projects/chap14

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in current_user
app/views/todos/index.html.erb:21:in _app_views_todos_index_html_erb___949818655437808348_39324440
app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:8:in index
```

Here's the code for my application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

   helper_method :current_user


      private

      def current_user
        if session[:user_id]
          @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
        else
          @current_user = nil
        end
      end

      def check_login
        unless authorized?
          redirect_to "/auth/identity"
        end
      end


      def logged_in?
        if session[:user_id]
          return true
        else
          return false
        end
      end

      protected
       def authorized?
          logged_in? && (request.get? || current_user.admin?)
       end    

end."
```

And here's my todos_controller.rb:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_login
  # GET /todos
  # GET /todos.json
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @todos }
    end
  end

  # GET /todos/1
  # GET /todos/1.json
  def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @todo }
    end
  end

  # GET /todos/new
  # GET /todos/new.json
  def new
    @todo = Todo.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @todo }
    end
  end

  # GET /todos/1/edit
  def edit
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /todos
  # POST /todos.json
  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo, status: :created, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /todos/1
  # PUT /todos/1.json
  def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.update_attributes(params[:todo])
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }

        @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
        if @todo.completed == true
          @todo.user_who_completed = current_user.email
          @todo.save
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todos/1
  # DELETE /todos/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @todo.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todos_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end."

And my app/views/todos/index.html.erb file:

"<h1>Listing todos</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
    <th>Completed date</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% for todo in @todos %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= todo.name %></td>
    <td><%= todo.completed %></td>
    <td><%= todo.completed_date %></td>
    <td><%= todo.user %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', todo %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_path(todo) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', todo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>S
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<%= link_to 'New Todo', new_todo_path %>
<% end %>
```

I'm new to rails and have no clue about what the error message means, nor its cause.  I want the visitor to land on the todos/index.html page.  I have my root route set accordingly. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please, include `index.html.erb` view.

Comment: The index.html.erb view from the todos directory is included.  Thanks, kalelc

Comment: Ok, in the line `if current_user.admin?`. `current_user` (i suppose that is the User model) have an admin field to check ?

Comment: This is the code for my user.rb model:                                                     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

  def User.create_with_omniauth(auth) 
    user = User.new()
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    user.save
    return user
  end
end

Comment: look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from `User.find`. It's described in the [Documentation for find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

It's telling you that there is no `User` that has that id. Somehow you have saved a user id into your session that corresponds to a user that doesn't currently exist.

You should probably examine how you are storing user ids to the session and under what circumstances that user could be getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your loop. If conditional it is outside the cycle.

Check solution view:

```
<h1>Listing todos</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
    <th>Completed date</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% for todo in @todos %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= todo.name %></td>
    <td><%= todo.completed %></td>
    <td><%= todo.completed_date %></td>
    <td><%= todo.user %></td>
    <% if current_user.admin? %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', todo %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_path(todo) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', todo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Recommendations

- Check your question. You have the code view with the controller code.
- Be careful with indentation.